# How do I delete friends on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, friends, delete

How can I **permanently delete friends from my Facebook** account?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### To remove a friend:

1. Click "Account" on the upper-right part of the screen
2. Click "Edit Friends" (first option under your profile picture)
3. On the left sidebar, under the "Lists" section, click "Friends".
4. Find the friend(s) you want to remove (you may need to click the arrows at the top or bottom of the list) and click the "X" button on the right.
5. A message will pop up asking if you really want to remove them. Click "Remove".

#### If you want to block someone, so they can't contact you at all:

1. Click "Privacy Settings" under the "Account" button on the upper-right part of the screen
2. Under the "Block Lists" section at the bottom of the page, click "Edit your lists".
3. Type the name or email address of the person you want to block, and click the corresponding "Block This User" button.
4. If you want to unblock them later, follow the same steps, but click the "(remove)" link next to their name/email address in the list.

Comment: way to copy someone else's answer... and post it 3 minutes AFTER they did. Lame - downvote

Comment: @Book 'em Danno: When I started my answer, there weren't any other answers. Apparently, we were both writing our answers at the same time, and mike finished his before I did.

Comment: No worries Matt... the point of the site is to get the best answer for the person asking! Thanks for contributing!

Answer (score 7):

**To Remove Friends - or more specifically "Relationships"**

1. Log into your facebook account via: http://www.facebook.com/
2. Click "Account" from the top right hand side of the header, and select the first option "Edit Friends". That will take you to your editable friends list: http://www.facebook.com/home.php?#!/friends/?ref=tn
3. Select the "X" next to the friend that you wish to remove.

*Note that you will be removing the connection between you and the friend, and not the actual friend. In other words, you are deleting the "friendship", not the "friend" (read: You can't delete other peoples facebook profiles).

**To block friends from ever seeing you again:**

1. Go to "Privacy Settings" in the account link: http://www.facebook.com/#!/settings/?tab=privacy&ref=mb
2. Select "Block Lists" from the bottom of the page.
3. From there you can add names and emails of people you want to block.

**More Resources**

There are a number of other things you can do to manage relationships w/ people. For instance I like to leave people as friends, however add them to specific "lists". That way only people on specific lists can see my posts, pictures, etc. I can also chose which list to share with when I post, or chose to share with all.

All this is outlined in the facebook help center under the "friends" topic: http://www.facebook.com/help/?page=441

Answer (score 5):

A much simpler way is to go to that friend's profile page, and then at the bottom of the left column (below their picture), the last thing in that column there is an option: `Remove from Friends`.

Answer (score 0):

Click "Account" on the upper-right part of the screen. Click "Edit Friends" (first option under your profile picture) On the left sidebar, under the "Lists" section, click "Friends". Find the friend(s) you want to remove (you may need to click the arrows at the top or bottom of the list) and click the "X" button on the right.

Answer (score -2):

If You Want To Remove Somebody from your friends on facebook.com
Example:i want to delete sarah jake,i go to her proifle
you'll find something that says (friends) ,that means you have her on contacts,click on settings and click unfriend

Comment: How is your answer different to the ones already given?