# Blocking people on Facebook without flagging them as spammers

Tags: facebook, friends

I want to block a [former] friend from seeing me on Facebook, but not flag them as a spammer. How do I do that?

<sub>Note - [How can I know if one of my friends on Facebook is blocking me?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/696/how-can-i-know-if-one-of-my-friends-on-facebook-is-blocking-me) is not related.</sub>

Comment: Isn't deleting his name from your friends list enough?

Comment: Does not deleting them - http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3497/how-do-i-delete-friends-on-facebook - work, followed by locking down your privacy settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to the Facebook [privacy settings](http://www.facebook.com/settings/?tab=privacy) page and click on the `Block Lists` link you can block people by either name or email.

In addition you can block them by going to their profile page and clicking on the `Report/Block this person` link in the sidebar and then selecting `Block this person`.

This will pretty much remove their total access to your account:

> If you block someone, they will not be
>   able to find you in a Facebook search,
>   see your profile, or interact with you
>   through Facebook channels (such as
>   Wall posts, Poke, etc.). Any Facebook
>   ties you currently have with a person
>   you block will be broken (for example,
>   friendship connections, Relationship
>   Status, etc.). Note that blocking
>   someone may not prevent all
>   communications and interactions in
>   third-party applications, and does not
>   extend to elsewhere on the Internet.extend to elsewhere on the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

With the new Facebook email being rolled out to everyone in the coming *months*, there will be more features to block and filter messages from your friends...see this article from Yahoo! Tech for more info:

> http://news.yahoo.com/s/yblog_technews/20101115/tc_yblog_technews/facebooks-modern-messaging-system-is-not-an-email-killer-yet
>
> Finally, there's a filter for your in box based on your Friends list — or, to be more specific, you'll get three in boxes: one for messages from your Facebook friends (or others that you specifically designate), one for everything else that isn't junk (you can also demote annoying Facebook friends to the "Other" in box if you like), and of course, the "Junk" folder for spam.
>
> In your Facebook privacy settings, you'd get the option of restricting incoming messages to those sent from your Facebook pals (or just your friends and "friends of friends").